# Can we able to export the file using Freefile with form fields instead of views in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm trying to generate a csv file from lotus notes. Is it possible to get field values from form using freefile? In my case the views doesn't show all the fields which i'm looking for. I have referred some of the sites but no answer. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

I have tried this code atleast to print header but its not working

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase 
Dim uiview As NotesUIView
Dim vw As NotesView 
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim form As NotesForm 
Dim session As NotesSession 
Dim Field As NotesItem  
Dim fileName As variant 
Dim Date1(1 To 3) As String
Dim headerString As String
Dim header As Variant
Dim fieldString As String
Dim fieldList As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long,seqno As Integer,count As Long
Dim fileNum As Integer
Dim rowstring As String  
Dim cns As String 



Sub Initialize
    Set uiview = ws.CurrentView 
    Set view = uiview.View 
    Set session=New NotesSession 
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase 
    fileName = ws.SaveFileDialog(False,"File name",, "E:\samp" & ".csv") 
    Call Exit_Form(db)
End Sub 


Function Exit_Form(db As NotesDatabase)
    fileNum% = FreeFile() 
    Open fileName For Output As fileNum% 
    On Error GoTo errorhandler 
    headerString ="UNID,S.No,SectionName,Year,Discount,Formula,Final Price"  
    header = Split(UCase(headerString),",") 
    Set form=db2.Getform("Form1") 
    i=1 
    j=1 
    count1=0
    ForAll a In header
        Print #fileNum%, a
    End ForAll
errorhandler:
    MsgBox  "ExitForm function" +Error + CStr(Erl) 
    Exit Function 
End Function
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong classes.

A "Form" is a design element to show "Documents" in a NotesDatabase. There is no information about the data in there.

You need to get NotesDocument- Objects, and from there you can read the data using GetItemValue- Method.

In addition I would not use the "antique" technique of freefile but use the class "NotesStream" for it.

To e.g. export all documents in a database (means: all different forms are used) you can do something like:

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim stream as NotesStream
Dim lineInFile as String
Dim itemList as Variant
Dim i as Integer

Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase
Set dc = db.AllDocuments
Set stream = ses.CreateStream

....

Call stream.Open( fileName )

Call stream.WriteText( headerLine, EOL_CRLF )

itemList = Split( "ItemFromDocument1,ItemFromDocument2,...", "," )

Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument()


While not doc is Nothing
  For i = 0 to ubound( itemList )
    If i = 0 then
      writeLine = Cstr( doc.GetItemValue( itemList(i) )(0) )
    Else
      writeLine = writeList & "," & Cstr( doc.GetItemValue( itemList(i) )(0) )
    End If
  Next
  Call stream.WriteText( writeLine, EOL_CRLF )
  Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend

Call stream.Close
```

You could do the same with all documents in a specific folder or view:

```
Dim view as NotesView
Set view = db.GetView( "NameOfFolderOrView" )

...

Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument()
While not doc is Nothing

  ... 

  Set doc = view.GetNextDocument( doc )
Wend
```

Beware: This approach is quite ugly. It does not consider multi value fields, it does not escape commas that are probably in one of the field values and it does not have any error handling... but at least it is a start.